# MapInfo - programmatically find if layer is hidden

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am working on an integrated mapping project. I would like a button that toggles a layer. I could hold the layers status in a variable and then show/hide it as appropriate but this seems a little hacky.

Is there a way to find out whether a layer's "display" value is set to on or off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/11.0/MapBasicReference.pdf

Page 364.

LayerInfo( window_id, layer_number, 9 )

LAYER_INFO_DISPLAY (9) will return the following:

SmallInt indicating how and whether this layer is
displayed; return value will be one of these
values:

• LAYER_INFO_DISPLAY_OFF (0) the layer is not displayed

• LAYER_INFO_DISPLAY_GRAPHIC (1) objects in this layer appear in their “default”
style—the style saved in the table

• LAYER_INFO_DISPLAY_GLOBAL (2) objects in this layer are displayed with a
“style override” specified in Layer Control

• LAYER_INFO_DISPLAY_VALUE (3)
objects in this layer appear as thematic
shading

Comment: How do you go about finding the layer number from the layer name?

Comment: You would need to use MapperInfo to find out the number of layers in the map window, then do a for loop, testing the layer name against each of the layers in the Map Window.

Comment: @James +1 nice one

Comment: Please note that there is an issue with MapBasic regarding "turning on" the visibility of the layer. As you can see from James' description above, there is one value for OFF (_OFF), but two values for ON (_GRAPHIC and _GLOBAL). So in order to turn on the layer in the right way, you need to store the value for the layers visible setting (either GRAPHIC or GLOBAL) and then when you turn the visibility on again act depending on how it was when you turned it off.

Comment: Every day's an adventure with MapBasic!

Comment: I'm actually only using this on group layers at the moment. This means the syntax is actually slightly different (GroupLayerInfo() instead of LayerInfo()) but it also means that I there is only "on" or "off" which could be a potential solution for someone stuck with the above problem - group everything!